# Firestore Analytics - Is there a limit to the number of parameter's values in one event?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

So let's say for example, I have user_id#1234 in chat room_id#4321 and I'm keeping track of:

1. The total number of messages for this particular room_id#4321, and
2. The total number of messages user_id#1234 sends in this room - *(It's important to associate the user's messages with the room because I need to track the total user's message count PER each chat room.)*

Here's the approach I got so far in my attempt to keep it to one event: On Firestore Analytics, I've created a custom dimension with the event "room_messages" and I'm able to log the events like so every time a message is sent:

```
firebase
  .analytics()
  .logEvent("room_messages", {
    room_id: room_id,
    user_room: `${user_id}-${room_id}`,
  });
```

But particularly for the user_room parameter, since there could be so many users and rooms, **is there a limit on the number of parameter values?** ie there could be a ton of the `event (room_messages) -> parameter (user_room) -> value (user_id-room_id)`

And on top of that, **how do you even view these events and their parameters for insights?** Whether on Firestore or Google Analytics, it seems like I can view all the total events that have occurred just fine, but for viewing the events AND their parameters, I am only able to view that from what events were triggered in the last 30 minutes.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Update: The parameter has to also be defined using Custom Definitions. Now the room_id tracking information shows up on the room_messages event page.